# Why is the short-circuit logical 'and' operator not used when comparing two nullables for equality?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a method which compares two nullable ints and prints the result of the comparison to the console:

```
static void TestMethod(int? i1, int? i2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i1 == i2);
}
```

And this is the result of its decompilation:

```
private static void TestMethod(int? i1, int? i2)
{
    int? nullable = i1;
    int? nullable2 = i2;
    Console.WriteLine((nullable.GetValueOrDefault() == nullable2.GetValueOrDefault()) & (nullable.HasValue == nullable2.HasValue));
}
```

The result is more or less what I expected but I wonder why the non-short-circuit version of the logical 'and' operator (&) is used instead of the short-circuit version (&&). It seems to me that the latter would be more efficient - if one side of the comparison is already known to be false then there is no need to evaluate the other side. Is the & operator necessary here or is  this just an implementation detail that is not important enough to bother about?

Comment: No reason, unless the operation in the right executes something like increasing a number or something while evaluating. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator) example in the documentation.

Comment: The short-circuit evaluation may involve a jump while the other one does not; the pure computation may be faster.

Comment: `&&` adds *conditional* jump (`JZ`, `JNZ` etc.) if condition is predicted wrongly by CPU branch predictor the fine is *painful* (about `10` ticks); `&` is just a multiplication (`1/3..1` tick)

Comment: Where did you  get this decompiled code from? [sharplib.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQFEAeAHJzkCWA9gHYBqUCBUwANigD4ACADAARMCMA3ALABQTAMwcATGwDCbAN4C28jpwBsHACxsAKihgBZCDAAWRACYAKAiRgB+NgU4AaW5ZsFRASgGz+CxQE5znGwAvEG27nz8AL4CkUA==) shows `&&`

Comment: I'm using ILSpy on a generated binary. Compiled with Visual Studio 15.8.8. Same behavior is for debug and release versions. No branching instructions are emitted which suggests it's not decompiler issue.

Comment: When I switch compiler version to master then non-short-circuit operator is used: [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgUBmLAJgwGEMBvIjRrbANiwBYMAVOWAWTgwAFgHsAJgAoAlgDsYAfgxTsAGiVzFU8gEoi9Qk2YBOadgwBec0p0FCAXyJ2gA)
So I guess this is quite fresh optimization.

Comment: I do not know if this behaviour has changed recently or not, but I would strongly recommend that you ensure that optimizations are turned on before considering whether the compiler does or does not do an optimization. That sounds obvious, but you'd be surprised at the number of people who ask questions about "bad" optimizations who have forgotten to turn optimizations on. In some versions of C# the nullable lowering code was deliberately very naive if optimizations were turned off.

Comment: Yes, optimizations were turned on. Turning them off changed almost nothing in this case.
Btw. I found GitHub roslyn issue that changed the behaviour of lifted comparison operators. As suggested, the reason is that when & operator is used then no branches are necessary, so the performance should improve:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17261

Comment: Well then, odds are good that the sub-optimal codegen using `&&` was my fault, and that it only took my colleagues five years to notice and fix the problem to use `&`. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The result is more less what I expected but I wonder why non-short-circuit version of logical and operator (&) is used instead of short-circuit version (&&). It seems to me that the latter would be more efficient - if one side of comparison is already known then there is no need to evaluate the other side.  Is there a reason that mandates usage of & operator or this is just implementation detail that is not important enough to bother?

That's a great question.

First off, I worked on the code generators for both the pre-Roslyn nullable lowering code, and for the original implementation in Roslyn.  This is some tricky code with a lot of opportunities for mistakes and missed optimizations. I wrote a long series of blog articles on how the Roslyn nullable lowering optimizer works, which begins here:

https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

If this subject interests you, this series of articles will probably be a big help. Part three is particularly germane as it discusses a related question: for nullable arithmetic, do we generate `(x.HasValue & y.HasValue) ? new int?(x.Value + y.Value) : new int?()` or use `&&` or use `GetValueOrDefault` or what? (The answer of course is I tried all of them and picked the one that makes the fastest smallest code.)  The series however does not consider your specific question here which is about nullable equality.  Nullable equality has slightly different rules than ordinary lifted arithmetic.

Of course, I have not been at Microsoft since 2012, and they may have changed it since then; I wouldn't know.  (UPDATE: Looking at the linked issue in the comments above, it seems likely that I missed an optimization in my original implementation in 2011, and that this was fixed in 2017.)

To answer your specific question: the problem with `&&` is that it is *more expensive* than `&` when the work being done on the right side of the operator is *cheaper* than the test-and-branch.  Test-and-branch is not just more instructions. It is, obviously, a branch, which has lots of knock-on effects. At the processor level, branches require branch prediction, and branches can be predicted wrong. Branches mean more basic blocks, and remember, the jit optimizer *runs at run time*, which means the jit optimizer has to be *fast*. It is allowed to say "too many basic blocks in this method, I'm going to skip some optimizations", and so maybe adding more basic blocks unnecessarily is a bad thing.

To make a long story short, the C# compiler will generate "and" operations as eager if the right side has no side effect and the compiler believes that evaluating `left & right` will be faster and shorter than evaluating `left ? right : false`.  Often the cost of evaluating `right` is so cheap that the cost of the branch is *more expensive* than just doing the eager arithmetic.

You can see this in areas other than the nullable optimizer; for example, if you have

```
bool x = X();
bool y = Y();
bool z = x && y;
```

then that will be generated as `z = x & y` because the compiler knows that there is no expensive operation to be saved; `Y()` has *already* been called.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the compiled CIL code (Roslyn 2.0) you can actually see (line IL_0016) the `br.s` instruction that does a short-circiut to the `Console.WriteLine()` call if the results of the `GetValue()` methods aren't equal (IL_0013). I guess it's your *decompiler* that does not care about displaying it properly as `&&`.

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldarg.0
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  ldarg.1
IL_0004:  stloc.1
IL_0005:  ldloca.s   V_0
IL_0007:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()
IL_000c:  ldloca.s   V_1
IL_000e:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()
IL_0013:  beq.s      IL_0018

IL_0015:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0016:  br.s       IL_0028

IL_0018:  ldloca.s   V_0
IL_001a:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
IL_001f:  ldloca.s   V_1
IL_0021:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
IL_0026:  ceq
IL_0028:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
IL_002d:  nop
IL_002e:  ret
```

Comment: In my case generated code looks different - there are no branching instructions in the compiled method at all ( I'm using Visual Studio 15.8.8).

Comment: Recent roslyn master generates non-short-circuit version so it looks like a recent optimization: [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgcBmIgJgIGECBvKgzo4gNiIBYCAFTiwAsnBgALAPYATABRoAdjAD8BNMSSbVGtPQCUVdpS7cAnEuIEAvLc1GKlAL5UXQA=)